# Joomla 2.5, Accessing template parameters in component's template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

What is the correct way to access template parameters in components template in Joomla 2.5?

There are something implementations for earlier versions of Joomla but not for 2.5.
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2166990#p2166903

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I *think* this might be what you're looking for:

```
$app        = JFactory::getApplication();
$template   = $app->getTemplate(true);
$params     = $template->params;
$variable   = $params->get('variable');
```

Comment: Just a note here that $template seems to be used elsewhere as a variable and so causes an error.  Replace that with a different name and this still works in the latest Joomla.